# Ignore Folder on Gitlab when merging to master

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge

I have question about gitlab, I did some search but could not find what i am looking for.
I want master branch to ignore a folder or files. so when i push my files from local machine to gitlab repo or branch different than master the folder is there and then I want to  make merge request to master without that specific folder, is that possible ?

Comment: If you don’t want the folder in the branch, don’t add its files to the branch.

Comment: Thanks for reply @matt, you mean dont push to branches ? or how ?

Comment: I mean what's in the commit at the end of the branch is what gets merged. You can't say "merge but not really". You can constitute the commit however you like; the time to keep the folder out of it was when you made the commit.

Comment: Yeah i know that but i need the files to be in branches but not in the master branch

Comment: I'm sorry but what you are describing is impossible. A file cannot be "in" a branch and you then merge that branch to master but _not_ that file. That would not be a merge.

Comment: Understood I thought there is a way something like gitignore but for branches. Anyway thank you for information :)

Comment: What you are describing is not at all like gitignore either.

Comment: let me rephrase then maybe i couldnt explain: 
I want master branch to ignore folder from other branch in gitlab like gitlab ignores files/folder when we put in our project .gitignore file.